# Need help finding a specific folder for a friend

Tags: folders

I am a Windows user, so I have no idea what the Mac equivalent of different locations in Windows are, but they still came to me for some reason...

The folder I am trying to find for them is their equivalent of `C:\Users\taj1994\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Cockatrice`

Where would they be able to find this folder?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely `~/Library/Application Support/Cockatrice`

1. `~` denotes the user's home directory. This should exist in their sidebar already, labeled with their name.
2. Library is hidden on Mac OS X Lion and above. The easiest way is have the Finder active, hold the option key (`⌥`) and click the 'Go' menu. This will reveal the 'Library' folder that you can select.

The rest of the paths should be able to be accessed normally.

Comment: /Library/Application Support/Cockatrice could also be relevant for applications installed for all users.  In this instance, the question specifically refers to the location under the users profile location, so unlikely to be relevant, but included for completeness.